# How can i get the value of previous url in php code?

Tags: php

How can i get the value of previous url in php code?

Here is the url page1.php

```
http://localhost/spk/kelulusan_process.php?lulus=10003
```

page2.php:
I want to get the parameter from the previous url in page1.php. I use

```
<?php 
$_GET['lulus'];
?>
```

But the value is null.

Comment: try `echo $_GET['lulus'];`

Comment: i have try it.but the value still null.

Comment: I guess you should use session variables.

Answer (score 1):

For $_GET to work you have to redirect user using form action

Or you can do that by setting session variables and access them any page

Answer (score 1):

You can try `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]`

But don't forget to escape `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]` since it's common for attacks.

Better is to store the current page in a `$_SESSION` var.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}
$_SESSION['lastpage'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Then when loading the next page:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}
// now you can access the last page
$lastpage = $_SESSION['lastpage'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot display `$_GET['lulus'];` in page2.php unless you write get parameter in page2.php.

Your code is redirect from page1.php to page2.php, You must set `$_GET['lulus'];` into one session and echo in page2.php

Page1.php

```
<?
    $_SESSION['GET'] = $_GET['lulus'];
?>
```

Page2.php

```
<?
    echo $_SESSION['GET'];
?>
```

Instead, echo $_GET['lulus'], you should echo in page2.php $_SESSION. Because $_SESSION variable was overrode by $_GET itself.

Comment: look at my newest answer

Comment: thanks. i got it. i forget to put session_start() in page1.php

Answer (score 0):

page2.php

```
    <?php 
echo htmlspecialchars($_GET["lulus"]);
?>
```

how are you trying to pass from page 1?
if through a form set the method to get and action to page2.php

in page1.php make sure you set the name

```
    <form method="get" action="page2.php">
<input type="text" name="lulus">
<input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send">
```

Comment: `$link = $_GET["lulus"]; echo "<a href="page2.php?" . $link . "\">page 2</a>";` or page1.php  `$_SESSION['GET'] = $_GET['lulus'];` page2.php `echo $_SESSION['GET'];`

Comment: thanks. i have try it but the value still null. i want to get the value of lulus "10003".

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` ... hopefully this will help you. And parse url something like below:

```
$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ; //http://localhost/spk/kelulusan_process.php?lulus=10003

$array = explode("?lulus=",$url);

echo $array[1];
```

Comment: i have try it. but it show the whole url. i just want the value of 10003. by the way, thanks.

Comment: You need to parse url

Comment: You are welcome..If you think my answer help you to solve your problem so please don't forget to accept answer.